# MIUI10 android textview setOnTouchListener ACTION_UP not called

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener, motionevent, miui

I am confused about this strange problem. Normally, on many phones, this is not a problem. But I tried three MIUI10 phones with this problem, and other systems have not encountered it. Perhaps this is a MIUI10 system bug?

If you have a MIUI10 phone, please help test it.

And **how can I solve this problem to be compatible with many devices?** All help is welcome.

The code is as follows, very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="#1ad9ca"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Hold to talk" />

</RelativeLayout>

findViewById(R.id.text).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_CANCEL");
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

And in my device, **Hold TextView for a few seconds and raise my hand**, ACTION_CANCEL is called, and **ACTION_UP is not called**. Here are the logs:

```
D/MainActivity: ACTION_DOWN
D/MainActivity: ACTION_MOVE
D/MainActivity: ACTION_MOVE
D/MainActivity: ACTION_CANCEL
```

And **I want to do some logic in ACTION_UP case**, not in ACTION_CANCEL case.

The test device info:

```
Phone name: Xiaomi 8
Android system version: Android 9
MIUI system version: MIUI 10.1.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Verified on my miui phone, this problem occurs only on 10.2.x.x version, when upgrading to 10.3.3.0, the problem no more occurs.

While dispatching ACTION_UP event, miui intercepts this event and changes action from ACTION_UP to ACTION_CANCEL, but nothing popup shows on screen, seems like a bug on 10.2.x.x.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug on MIUI10.